# How do I use row-level permissions in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Google announced this feature today, but I don't see any docs for it. How can I grant row-level permissions to a user?

For example, let's say I have a table `private.all_customers` with the schema `{customer:string, id:integer, is_secret:boolean}`.

I like to give our salespeople access to the fields `customer` and `id`, but not `is_secret`, and moreover, I'd like to give to give them access to only those rows where `is_secret = false`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key part of row-level permissions is that you're actually giving permission to a view. The view defines the rows and columns in that you want the delegated user to see, without giving them access to the underlying table.

To do this, create the view that will return the rows and columns that you'd like the user to see. For the example above, the view would look like:

```
SELECT customer, id FROM private.all_customers where is_secret = false
```

Then I can save this as the view "public.public_customers", and share the `public` dataset with the analysts.

Note that, so far, this does *NOT*  mean that the analysts will have access to the data. If they try to run it now, they'll get an error. Merely having access to a view that reads a table doesn't give you access to the underlying data on that table. If it did, then anyone could just create a view to read any data that they wanted to see.

The second step is adding that view to the ACL of the `private` dataset. What this does is records that the view should have access to the data. This way the owner of the `private` dataset can audit who has access to their data, and revoke it if necessary.

The easiest way to add the view to the ACL is to use the BigQuery Web UI. If you click on the arrow next to the `private` dataset name in the Web UI and click "Share this dataset", it will bring up a dialog box that lets you edit the ACL. 
At the bottom of that dialog it will show "Add People" and a clickable icon on the left. If you click on that icon, you should be able to select "Authorized View". Once that is selected, you should enter the fully-qualified name -- `project:dataset.view` of the view. In our example, that would be `my-project:public.public_customers`. Hit 'Add' and it will show up in the list, and then hit "Save Changes" to commit.

Once the view has been added to the ACL, anyone with access to the 'public' dataset should be able to run queries against the `public.public_customers` view.

For more advanced usage of this feature, which will allow you to give different answers to different users, see this question: [How do I give different users access to different rows without creating separate views in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683423/how-do-i-give-different-users-access-to-different-rows-without-creating-separate)

Comment: I am able to set up row level permission within the organization. But outside I am unable to provide access. It gives "Data Set Configuration Error

Data Studio cannot connect to your data set.

Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set"