# BigQuery Data Connectors: How to limit the accessible data by field value

Tags: google-bigquery, visualization

I have one large BigQuery table with multiple different clients analytics data stored within it. Clients wish to connect the table to one of the [data visualization tools](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/) partnered with Google. My worry is regarding the potential for client data to be mixed. Is there a sure-fire way of ensuring that the data provided to each client is filtered to only contain their own?

The Clients data all have an associated account_id. Can I use this field to filter by? If the answer is no to filtering, then is the best approach filtering the large BigQuery table into smaller ones for each client?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683423/how-do-i-give-different-users-access-to-different-rows-without-creating-separate

Comment: Note that the relevant function with standard SQL is `SESSION_USER()`, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a view that filters data by a specific account_id and share view with your customer. Customer will only be able to query your data via this view, and this will not be able to bypass the filter on account_id.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views
In particular pay attention to "Creating Authorized Views" section.
Also note, that even though customers will access only their data, they will still be charged for scanning the whole table.
This problem can be addressed in several ways:
1. Run a query that is reading data of a specific customer and writes it to customer's dataset. Unfortunately we do not yet provide convenient scheduling mechanism to run such query on a regular bases.
2. In general write your data so that each customer goes to a separate table.
Note that Authorized view is the most feasible approach for now. Option 1 should fairly soon become available as one of the Data Sources for BigQuery Data Transfer Service.