# How to restrict BigQuery's dataset access for everyone having (Project level Viewer) role

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I want to restrict access for 1 dataset in BigQuery so that no one except 1 user(me) is able to view that dataset. From the documentation, it seems that this isn't possible unless I change my project-level permissions and remove the `Editor` role from there.

Currently, N(10-12) people have project-level `Editor` access on my Google project.  They all interact with multiple services there from time to time.  I would like to keep it that way, or at least have a new Role with almost the same permissions.

From my current understanding of `Google IAM` permissions, we can do this by giving resource-level access to users. But If I give BigQuery Editor role to a user, they are still able to view/access all `datasets`.

To counter this, I would have to give more granular level access to each user,  Which means giving individual dataset level access to all users.  Again that means If I have 
10/12 people and 10/12 datasets this can get hard to manage.

Is there a better way to do it, I mean somehow I can specify all `Editors` or `Custom Role` can access everything like they are already doing except this particular `dataset`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define access control on table. Only down to dataset level, but there are other options that can help you:

As mentioned per BigQuery's documentation about [creating datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#dataset-naming):

> Datasets **that begin with an underscore are hidden** from the navigation pane in the BigQuery web UI and the classic web UI. You can still query tables and views in these datasets even though **they are not visible.**

You can give yourself `bigquery.datasets.create` in order to create these "hide" datasets away from this users or assign the following Cloud IAM roles to yourself, as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#required_permissions):

- `bigquery.dataEditor`
- `bigquery.dataOwner`
- `bigquery.user`
- `bigquery.admin`

Another solution is to create [authorized views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views) within BigQuery. As stated here:

> An authorized view allows you to share query results with particular users and groups **without giving them access to the underlying tables**. You can also use the view's SQL query to restrict the columns (fields) the users are able to query.

Finally I attach a post about [how to control access to BigQuery at row level with groups](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-control-access-to-bigquery-at-row-level-with-groups-1cbccb111d9e), that can help you get a better idea on how row access level works.

I will also attach this question about giving users access to different rows without creating separate views [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683423/how-do-i-give-different-users-access-to-different-rows-without-creating-separate)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer.  I understand we can do above approaces but doesnt assigning permissions for every user for every data set gets hard to manage? My base question is: IS IT the ONLY WAY to do it? Isnt there any easy way to manage permissions.  e.g: If I could keep Editor at project level and then specify somehow that: X dataset cant be accessed even by Editors

Comment: I think the best possible way to manage them is to use underscore to name the datasets, in order to hide it from others. You can not give table access but you can utilize one of the solutions provided before in order to manage your user permissions. Also, to control or specify that X datases cant be accessed by X people, you can use [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-control-access-to-bigquery-at-row-level-with-groups-1cbccb111d9e) or use [authorized views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views) as you can keep your Editor role and limit access to the others.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution here is to have Terraform (or something else) manage the resources for you.

You can develop a module that creates the appropriate things for a user e.g. a dataset, a bucket, some perms, a service account etc.

That way all you need to do is add another user to your list and re-deploy. The other additional benefit here is that you can use the repo where the TF is stored as a source of truth.