# BigQuery row level security permissions

Tags: google-bigquery

Google announced in April 2015 support for BigQuery row level security permissions.

[Google blog announcement](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/take-your-big-data-to-new-places-with-Google-BigQuery.html)

Could anyone point me at any documentation or examples outlining how this feature may be used in practice ?

I understand this is similar to a question answered previously: [How do I use row-level permissions in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682618/how-do-i-use-row-level-permissions-in-bigquery)

However I was unsure if the answer regarding views was the new row level feature or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer you've linked to is the way to grant row-level permissions in BigQuery. If you want to give different views to different users based on who is accessing, check out this question: [How do I give different users access to different rows without creating separate views in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683423/how-do-i-give-different-users-access-to-different-rows-without-creating-separate).

Answer (score 1):

Row-level security is now available in BigQuery

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/row-level-security-intro