# Google BigQuery Access control

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some metadata tables and fact tables holding ad impression data for 100 clients. My clients want ad-hoc reporting on top of canned reports on their **own** data. 
I want to limit #of tables(to save storage cost) and thus do not want to create separate tables for each one of my client (holding only their own data). Creating a single table is advantageous but that raises lot of security concerns. 
Is there any way i can protect data-access so that clients cannot see each other's data ? 
As an advertiser agency (managing ad campaigns for my advertisers/clients), i want to run **cross-client** trend/pattern analysis and that is the only reason why i have decided to create only one table holding data for all of my 100 advertisers. Single table also removes query-join issues. I am creating Daily partitions(10TB each).I do want to "limit" data processing volume (to save query cost) when a particular client scans only his own data from partition holding data from other 99 clients. 
Could i seek help on my data model as well as how to ensure best security for data access in BigQuery ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give different users access to different rows without creating separate views in BigQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683423/how-do-i-give-different-users-access-to-different-rows-without-creating-separate)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to limit the number of tables? As far as I can tell, the [BigQuery storage pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#storage) only looks at the number of bytes stored.

For doing cross-client analysis, you can use [wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) to query up to 1000 tables.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Appreciate your support. I think, with Daily table partitions, we even don't need to depend upon wildcards and worry about limit of 1000 tables. Daily partition feature was also one of the reason behind creating a single table for storing all clients day together.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Please see Jordan's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683423/how-do-i-give-different-users-access-to-different-rows-without-creating-separate/29683424#29683424 I believe it covers your desired use case.

Comment: Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682618/how-do-i-use-row-level-permissions-in-bigquery for how to provide row-level access control using views.