# Google Data Studio User Security

Tags: looker-studio

I am in the process of creating a few dashboards for my organization. We currently use a few different cloud based applications where we authenticate with Google Chrome.

Does Google Data Studio have the ability secure access and or filter content based on your google account?

For example, if I create a dashboard with data for `User(s)@domain.com` will I be able to set a filter in the data source or dashboard to allow `USER A` to see only sales data they generated? My user population is over 5k so individual reports are not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Not natively. I'm not sure about your datsources but in Google Bigquery you can create views which serve the same purpose

[row permissions in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682618/how-do-i-use-row-level-permissions-in-bigquery)